Error 404 Not Found. Connecting my Nest.js with React via Axios
I'm using Nest.js on my backend and React on my front end.
It seems that I'm having a problem doing a Post request via Axios. Hence, I keep getting this 404 (Not found error).
Why am I still getting this 404 error?
// FrontEnd

import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const AddSched: React.FC = () => {
    const handleClick = async () => {


        try{
            const createNapTimeDto = {
                userId: 5, 
                babyId: 5, 
                date: new Date().toISOString()
            }
        
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/naptime/create', createNapTimeDto);
            console.log("Created object", response)
        }catch(error){
            console.error("There was an error", error)
        }
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Ready to log for Baby Axel</h2>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Nap Time</button>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Diaper Time</button>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Tummy Time</button>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Bath Time</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AddSched;



//backend

import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { NapTimeEntity } from '../naptime.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from 'src/user/user.entity';
import { CreateNapTimeDto } from '../dto/createNaptime.dto';
import { BabyEntity } from 'src/baby/baby.entity';
import { GetOneResponseDto } from '../dto/getOneResponse.dto';

@Injectable()
export class NapTimeService {


    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(NapTimeEntity)
        private readonly napTimeRepo: Repository<NapTimeEntity>,

        @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
        private readonly userRepo : Repository<UserEntity>,

        @InjectRepository(BabyEntity)
        private readonly babyRepo : Repository<BabyEntity>



    ){}


    async create(
        createNapTimeDto: CreateNapTimeDto
    ){

        //checks if user is existing
        const existingUser = await this.userRepo.findOneBy({id: createNapTimeDto.userId})
        if(!existingUser){
            throw new NotFoundException({
                status: "Error", 
                message: "UserID not found!"
            })
        }


        //checks if a babyId matches UserId
        const matchedBaby = await this.babyRepo.findOne({
            where: {
                id: createNapTimeDto.babyId,
                user: existingUser
            }
        })


        if(!matchedBaby){
            throw new NotFoundException({
                status: "error",
                message: "baby does not belong to the specified user"
            })
        }
        // Save to naptime entity
        const newNaptime = new NapTimeEntity;

        newNaptime.date = createNapTimeDto.date;
        newNaptime.babies = matchedBaby;
        newNaptime.user = existingUser; 
        await this.napTimeRepo.save(newNaptime)

        return{
            status: "OK",
            message: "New naptime created successfully", 
            data: {
                date: createNapTimeDto.date,
                babyId: createNapTimeDto.babyId,
                userId: createNapTimeDto.userId

            }
        }
    }

}


import { Controller, Logger, Body, Query} from '@nestjs/common';
import { NapTimeService } from '../service/naptime.service';
import { Post, Get, Patch } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateNapTimeDto } from '../dto/createNaptime.dto';
import { UpdateNapTimeResponse } from '../dto/updateNapTimeResponse.dto';

@Controller('naptime')
export class NapTimeController {

    private readonly logger = new Logger(NapTimeController.name);
    constructor(private readonly napTimeService: NapTimeService){}


    @Post('/create')
    async createNapTime(
    
        @Body() createNapTimeDto: CreateNapTimeDto
    ){

        try{

            return this.napTimeService.create(createNapTimeDto)

        }catch(error){
            this.logger.error(NapTimeController.name, error);
            throw error
        }
    }

}

Here are some of the things that I did:

Added CORS code on my backend.

Verified that the post request is working on the Postman.

Verified that my frontend runs at port 3001 and backend at 3000.



what is the message of the response when you received status 404 ? also verify if the data that you're sending is correct

What debugging have you done? You have several logic paths that can throw a NotFoundException

Kindly show the app.module.ts and main.ts file from the backend.

@LãNgọcHải -
in the console log this is the message:
POST http://localhost:3000/naptime/create 404 (Not Found)
There was an error 

@Phil
Here are some of the things i've done so far:
*Created Post request using Postman that seems to be working fine at the backend.
*Verified that my getAll request is working directly on the browser

Here's the actual github code:
https://github.com/markpakingan/baby-tracker-app.git

How about some simple logging in your NapTimeService, ie every time you throw a NotFoundException, also log something with the details.

@Phil - Not sure if I understand you correctly but on the terminal, I don't see any type of error after all despite my logger or notFoundException logs.
The only error that I see is on the Chrome browser on the console. I hope this helps

So your problem is that it responds with a 404. Since the URL does seem correct and works in Postman, the 404 must be coming from your code. I would assume that throwing a NotFoundException causes Nest to send a 404. So do some debugging and find out if it is either of your throw new NotFoundException(...) instances. If it is, the issue is either because createNapTimeDto.userId or createNapTimeDto.babyId are not found in your DB. It's not clear from your question where those values come from in your server-side code

Any chance you could add a screenshot of the working Postman request showing the URL and request body?

Just a quick check you can do on your axios request :
When creating an api with NestJS it come with the globalPrefix variable like this :
app.setGlobalPrefix(globalPrefix); // <= This variable
const port = process.env.NX_RC_PUBLIC_API;
const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
await app.listen(port, hostname);
Logger.log(
   ` Application is running on: http://${hostname}:${port}/${globalPrefix} | Version : ${process.env.VERSION}`
  );

Did you check you don't forget to add this to your request ?
When generating with NX for exemple the most common is "api" so you request should look like :
const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/naptime/create', createNapTimeDto);


I am not familiar to nest.js but from axios, the request process looks good to me. May be you can try with a different URL like google or https://mockapi.io/ to verify that an API request is working from your application. If request to any of these URL is working(response!=404), you should check your nest application.
